# Gradle build war file based on environment properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have a spring boot Gradle project which has multiple properties based on different environments for example `application-dev.properties`, `application-prod.properties` etc.

What I would like to do is, build a war file which only has a single `application.properties` file based on the environment arg.

I have the following which uses `processResources`

```
processResources {
    def profile = (project.hasProperty('profile') ? project.profile : 'prod').toLowerCase()
    include "**/application-${profile}.properties"
    rename {
        'application.properties'
    }
}
```

The only issue I am having is, that this does not include the all the static files in the resources folder. For example, in my resources folder I have static folder, templates folder and some other static files. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use doFirst to replace the properties of the environment.

like this

```
war {
doFirst {
    def propertyFile = file("build/resources/main/env_${branch}.properties")
    if(propertyFile.exists()){
        delete 'build/resources/main/env.properties'

        propertyFile.renameTo(file("build/resources/main/env.properties"))
    }
}}
```